# Vue3 how to fix error when running "vue add apollo"?

Tags: vue.js, apollo, vue-apollo

I created an app with Vue 3.

I ran vue add apollo and run into an error.
[image]

how do I fix this

Comment: This may maybe help: https://github.com/vuejs/apollo/issues/1129#issuecomment-906754821

Comment: so there is no easyway for vue3?